# R: shading specific tiles using geom_tile

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, heatmap

```
library(tidyverse)
## make data
set.seed(3)
dat <- matrix(runif(100, 0, 1), ncol=10)

## reshape data (tidy/tall form)
dat2 <- dat %>%
  tbl_df() %>%
  rownames_to_column('Var1') %>%
  gather(Var2, value, -Var1) %>%
  mutate(
    Var1 = factor(Var1, levels=1:10),
    Var2 = factor(gsub("V", "", Var2), levels=1:10)
  )

## plot data
frames <- data.frame(Var1 = c(1, 1, 3, 4),
                     Var2 = c(8, 10, 3, 2))
ggplot(dat2, aes(Var1, Var2)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = round(value, 1))) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red") +
  geom_rect(data=frames, size=1, fill=NA, colour="black",
            aes(xmin=Var1 - 0.5, xmax=Var1 + 0.5, ymin=Var2 - 0.5, ymax=Var2 + 0.5))
```

[image]

I have a heat map here, and I've customized it so that certain tiles have black borders by specifying a data.frame called `frames` to contain the location of the tiles and then passing that into `geom_rect`.

I'd like to completely shade in 2 of the tiles black, but change the text color to white. The following data.frame contains the locations of these 2 tiles:

```
frames_shade <- data.frame(Var1 = c(3, 9), Var2 = c(5, 2))
```

Which function can I use to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overlay another geom_tile... I added the last statement here instead of your rectangle. This gets you black rectangles. I think the last line would do your white text, but the frames data frame needs to have those text values in it. It will give an error right now because *value* isn't in frames.

```
ggplot(dat2, aes(Var1, Var2)) +
geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) +  
geom_text(aes(label = round(value, 1))) +
scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red") +
geom_tile(data=frames,fill="black")  #+ 
#geom_text(data=frames,aes(label = round(value, 1)),colour="white")
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this. Do you know how to make ggplot display more digits? Currently it's only displaying 1 decimal point

Comment: You're rounding it to one decimal place `round(value,1)`. You can increase that and then you may want to change the size `geom_text(aes(label=round(value,2)),size=4)`